# How to use Fuse inside docker compose container in Google VM?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, fuse, google-cloud-sdk

Currently, a docker compose container is running on an Ubuntu GCP VM.
I try to mount a bucket inside a container with fuse, but not working.

```
Using mount point: /data/buckets/files
Opening GCS connection...
Opening bucket...
Mounting file system...

daemonize.Run: readFromProcess: sub-process: mountWithArgs: mountWithConn: Mount: mount: running fusermount: exit status 1

stderr:
fusermount: fuse device not found, try 'modprobe fuse' first
```

I tried to give him GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS from host machine service account, but failed.

What could be the problem? Any idea? Thx

Answer (score 2):

If I add it to the `capabilities` file then it works.

```
privileged: true
cap_add:
 - SYS_ADMIN
```